# Normalise Header on all worksheets VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and have been playing around with the basics.

What I'm tasked to do is to extract data from a certain row based on the header and column's data. Example, if column under the header "ENG JOBSCOPE" <> "", then extract row of that data.

However, i'm stuck at a point where when the macro loops thru all the worksheets, if the criteria that i want to find using range.find could not find, it'll give me error 91.

I've read up about using normalise but i can't seem to make it work.

Currently i'm using this code

```
J = 1

For Each ws In x.Worksheets

     For Each wks In y.Worksheets

       With x.Worksheets(ws.Name)
         LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
       End With

    For i=2 to Lastrow

     EJOB = Range("A1:DE1").Find(What:="ENG JOBSCOPE", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Column
     'Error 91 comes from the above line ^^^

       EJobs = ws.Cells(i, EJOB).Value

     If EJobs <>  "" then
          x.Sheets("ID").Rows(i).Copy
          y.Sheets("ID").Range("A" & j).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
          Application.CutCopyMode = False
          J=J+1

     End if
    Next i
   Next wks
  Next ws
 End sub
```

"ENG JOBSCOPE" is a header. However, some of the worksheet consist of "ENG JOB SCOPE".

Is there another method where i can use to make it so that it'll find the column number regardless of space or capitalization in between?

Also, some of the worksheet doesn't consist of the "ENG JOBSCOPE". Is there a way for the code to continue searching without it stopping with error 91? 
I've tried using on error goto next, but the data gets jumbled up.

I hope what i typed is sufficient enough or clear enough. If it isn't clear enough please tell me what is needed to type as i'm new to this forum.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

use wildcard.

```
EJOB = Range("A1:DE1").Find(What:="ENG*JOB*SCOPE", LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Column
```

If you want Find to work regardless of capitalisation, type MatchCase:=False.

Comment: Hi! thank you for the quick response. It seems to be taking out information from another header because there is another header named "CP ENG JOBSCOPE". Is it possible that I only want to search from "ENG JOBSCOPE / ENG JOB SCOPE"?

Comment: I have tested it and "CP ENG JOBSCOPE" is not picked. What:="ENG*JOB*SCOPE" means that the value in the cell must begin with "ENG".

Comment: Ohh yes, i realise my mistake is that the column i hide was wrong. It works brilliantly! Thank you so much!